# transform more row in one row oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How convert more row in one oracle sql?

Example:

```
Create table EMP(
        emp_id number,
        emp number,
        code number,
        date_start date,
        date_end date
    )
    
    
    Insert into EMP (emp_id,emp,code,date_start,date_end) VALUES (1,100,1,sysdate,sysdate + 1/24);
    Insert into EMP (emp_id,emp,code,date_start,date_end) VALUES (2,100,1,sysdate,sysdate + 1/24);
    Insert into EMP (emp_id,emp,code,date_start,date_end) VALUES (3,100,2,sysdate,sysdate + 1/24);
    Insert into EMP (emp_id,emp,code,date_start,date_end) VALUES (4,100,1,sysdate,sysdate + 1/24);
```

How get resault as:

```
EMP    CODE_1       CODE_2
----------------------------------
100    3 (hours)    1 (hours)
```

3 hours is date_end - date_start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT emp, code, 24 * (date_end - date_start) AS hours FROM emp)
PIVOT (
  SUM(hours) FOR code IN (
    1 AS code_1,
    2 AS code_2
  )
);
```

or conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT emp,
       SUM(CASE code WHEN 1 THEN 24 * (date_end - date_start) END) AS code_1,
       SUM(CASE code WHEN 2 THEN 24 * (date_end - date_start) END) AS code_2
FROM   emp
GROUP BY emp;
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

> | EMP | CODE_1 | CODE_2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 100 | 3 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a3543a0515e43edd151694355fe3216b)*